# how to use preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace to replace a word with a link html?

Tags: php

i am trying to use preg_match() in an if statement them preg_replace(). It was working fine until i found out that preg_replace is depricated and should be replaced with preg_replace_callback. So i replaced it but no luck it is not working, i need your help please to understand how i should use it in my case. I have read other questions here on stackoverflow and elsewhere but none is similar to my case

```
// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl1 = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl1, $discussion_text_with_links, $url1)) {
    // make the urls hyper links
    //$replaceWith = "<a href=".$url1[0]." class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a> ";
    $discussion_text_with_links = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl1, function($url1) {echo "<a href=".$url1[0]." class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a> ";}, $discussion_text_with_links);

} else {
    // The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl2 = "/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl2, $discussion_text_with_links, $url1)) {
        // make the urls hyper links
        //$replaceWith = "<a href=".$url1[0]." class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a> ";
        $discussion_text_with_links = preg_replace_callback($reg_exUrl2, function($url1) {echo "<a href=".$url1[0]." class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a> ";}, $discussion_text_with_links);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you hear that `preg_replace()` is deprecated?

Comment: The only thing that's deprecated is the `e` modifier, which was the old way to execute code when creating the replacement. You don't need to do that if you're just copying capture groups.

Comment: i was reading about depricated and found this on the php site https://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: oops !! i misunderstood ! it's maybe because i never used the e modifier

Comment: That says exactly what I just said: **The preg_replace() /e modifier is now deprecated**. It doesn't say that `preg_replace()` itself is deprecated.

Comment: Just use `preg_replace()` with `$0` in the replacement string to get the matched string.

Comment: thanks for clarifying so this should go as the answer, can you please place it as answer so i can check it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `preg_replace_callback()`. Just use `$0` in the replacement string of `preg_replace()`, it will be replaced with the string that was matched by the regexp.

```
$discussion_text_with_links = preg_replace(
    $reg_exUrl1, 
    "<a href='$0' class='hashtag_link' target='_blank'>$0</a>", 
    $discussion_text_with_links);
```

You can also refer to capture groups using `$1`, `$2`, etc.